# Add Glyphicon to titles?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am attempting to add glyphicon options to titles. Is there a way I can add a field to a content type in order to render the html showing the glyphicon? I am trying to add it to just the basic page content type and the page it shows on title click.

I tried adding a select list with the  inside as options for example, but it would not render the html.

EDIT:::

I tried the title html module, but it only allows a few elements. I would ideally like to add a select list to my content type that contains all the glyphicons i'd like to use on the page and i could just select which one to show before the title from that select list. It would then show the glyphicon before the title on save.

Comment: can you clarify the question a bit?

You want to have HTML in your title fields?

Comment: @jdu Updated the question a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easier way to do this will be using this module:

[***Icon API***](https://www.drupal.org/project/icon)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with adding a second custom field to allow the user to choose the glyph.

Once the user has set the title, selected the glyph and saved,  you can merge the two using a template file.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7

The one you'd want I think would be named something like this:  field--title--basic-page.tpl.php

In there, you can stick the value of the glyph next to the title.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Any example code you might have?

Comment: This exact approach is going to be tricky because the title for node pages isn't rendered out in the node template (it's in the page template).